# RXJS Combine x observables where n of them is optional

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to combine multiple observables into a single observable that is used to retrieve data from a server.

My initial approach was the following:

```
filters$ = combineLatest([
   filter1$,
   filter2$,
   filter3$
])
```

This way i could have a single observable of filters to go to the server with.

```
this.filters$.pipe(
   switchMap(filters => goToServer(filters))
)
```

However how do i approach this if one of the filters can be optional depending on the type of user using the system. if `filter3$`is only available to some users, the filters will never emit of the ones who do not have access to it. (The API handles this fine with that filter being optional)

I could approach this using `startWith()`

```
filters$ = combineLatest([
   filter1$,
   filter2$,
   filter3$.pipe(
      startWith(null)
   )
])
```

However this could give me multiple network requests for the users that DO have access to `filter3$` which ideally i would like to avoid.

Anyone know an elegant solution to this problem? a really awesome way would be if `combineLatest` accepted optional parameters, to only include if they have a value or disregard if they doesn't.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better then to setup the array to `combineLatest` differently? Maybe instead of `filter3$.pipe` something like: `userBasedCondition() ? filter3$ : of(null)`?

Comment: That could be a solution, but not a very reactive one. For it to change correctly when two different users use the same machine to log in right after one another (edge case i admit) it would have to be a rxjs chain. something along the lines of

`filter3Corrected$ = userInfo$.pipe(
   switchMap(userInfo => {
      userInfo.someRole ? filter3$ : of(null)
   }
)
`

That could probably work. altough i don't think it's very elegant :)

Comment: I think that's perfectly fine. At some point the decision is required, how you hide the fact is just preference, I guess. :)

Comment: It's probably a more explicit solution than simply marking the filter optional, since you would have a definitive explanation for when the filter is set, and when it's not. I am however curious if an optional solution is doable :)

Answer (score 3):

Define the array of observables and conditionally push the 3rd one.

```
const toBeUsedFilters = [filter1$, filter2$];
if (isFilter3Available) toBeUsedFilters.push(filter3$);

filters$ = combineLatest(toBeUsedFilters);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's could be the fully functional and reactive approach. 2filter$ and 3filter$ are all reusable

```
const 3filter$=filters$ = combineLatest([
   filter1$,
   filter2$,
   filter3$
]);

const 2filter$=filters$ = combineLatest([
   filter1$,
   filter2$,
]);

userInfo$.pipe(switchMap(userInfo => { userInfo.someRole ?3filter$  : 2filter$ } )
```